# MongoDB server migration causes slow in query performance

Tags: java, mongodb, docker, spring-data, jetty

Recently I migrated to latest mongodb server version from 3.2. Everything was running seamless in my local system before migration. But after migrating to mongodb server 3.6 all my queries are running slow while querying through spring-data-mongodb(2.0.4.RELEASE) java client. But in ubuntu system it works fine.

Even if running a query to get User document by username is taking around 1.7 sec from user collection of size 10.

My system configuration :

- OS : Windows 10 pro
- RAM: 16GB (DDR4)
- Storage : 256GB(SSD)
- 64 bit OS

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that you didn't set any indexes? Indexes have a big impact in queries like this.

Comment: @cagdasalagoz I don't think indexes matter for a collection of size 10. Anyways I have index for this collection.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Did you try using  "db.stats();" or "db.currentOp();" to see what actually is going on?